# Get Websphere MQ object authorizations via PCF

Tags: java, ibm-mq, pcf

Need to get the complete list of authorizations for MQ object (typically a queue), like the one returned by [dspmqaut](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083190_.htm) command, but with PCF.

Any idea how this could be done?

I believe this should be possible, as soon as MQ Explorer, supposed to operate with PCF, enables such function.

UPDATE

Need to do that in java, the regular attributes of the queue are already received without a problem (MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q, MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_STATUS, etc.)

FOLLOW UP to Josh comment, finally worked with the code below

```
PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_AUTH_RECS);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_AUTH_OPTIONS, MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_ENTITY_EXPLICIT+MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_NAME_ALL_MATCHING+MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_NAME_AS_WILDCARD);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_OBJECT_TYPE, MQConstants.MQOT_Q);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCACF_AUTH_PROFILE_NAME, "*");
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_AUTH_PROFILE_ATTRS, MQConstants.MQIACF_ALL);
```

Comment: What language are you using, what have you tried?  Have you reviewed this document [Inquire Authority Records on Multiplatforms](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087310_.htm)

Comment: Searching git for [MQCMD_INQUIRE_AUTH_RECS](https://github.com/search?l=&q=MQCMD_INQUIRE_AUTH_RECS&type=Code) brings up lots of examples of usage in various languages.

Comment: @JoshMc may I ask you to post this as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: Answer posted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is located in the IBM MQ Knowledge Center.  You can find the v9.0 KC page [Reference > Administration reference > Programmable command formats reference > Definitions of the Programmable Command Formats > Inquire Authority Records on Multiplatforms](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087310_.htm).

For examples of usage I did a git search for [MQCMD_INQUIRE_AUTH_RECS for Java](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=MQCMD_INQUIRE_AUTH_RECS&type=Code) which brings up brings up a couple of examples.  Take away the language restriction and you will have more examples, the PCF concept is the same across all languages.